# MYSQL Notifier: High Severity Error

Tags: mysql

Facing the below error:

MYSQL Notifier:

> High Severity Error

Error Message:

> Loading application settings failed. The application will continue
>   but may not behave as you would expect.

What could be the cause of this problem ?

Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Add proper information and context. When happens this? Have you changed anything? etc...

Answer (score 1):

This **[Link](https://superuser.com/questions/724234/mysql-notifier-high-severity-error-at-startup)** contains the same question and a answer.

Because it is about loading settings, try this (As mentioned in the above link)

1. Open a Run command window and type the following (from Windows Vista to Windows 8.1):

   `%AppData%\Roaming\Oracle\MySQL Notifier\`
2. Delete the `settings.config` at the mentioned location.